# Convert WriteableBitmap pixel format to Bgra32 in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I have a WriteableBitmap which loads the bitmap image from file(mostly bmp). The bitmap files I am using have different pixel formats such as Indexed8, Bgra32, etc etc. The problem is that my code only works for bgra32 pixel format. So I need help in converting the bitmaps to Bgra32 pixel format in c# wpf.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
 if (bmpSource.Format != PixelFormats.Bgra32)
     bmpSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bmpSource, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 0);
```